# Angular filtering by friend.brand.id inside of friends works, but can't use the || undefined trick to reset the filter when NULL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

So it's the year 2075 and immortal humans enslaved mortal humans. There is a store that sells mortal friends and is trying to build the app so that customers can manage their friends by filtering through them using their favorite brand. But apparently angular.js is broken.

```
<select ng-model="searchText2.id" ng-options="friend.brand.id as friend.name for friend in friends">
  <option value="">Select</option>
</select>

  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:{brand:searchText2 || undefined}">
```

I get a nice filtering going on here don't get me wrong, but the UX manager will feed me to the cyber-albino-ligers if the filter doesn't reset when I click select.

HERE IS THE PLUNKER ---> http://plnkr.co/edit/1MPc0BqQGPNIJZ9FRR6z?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cQPtoztzD17krRcXIXFZ?p=preview) with a possible solution.

Within the `filter` you could use a ternary statement to do what you intend.

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:{ brand:(searchText2.id === null) ? {id: undefined}: searchText2}">
```

When you select the default option of "Select a name" angular will set the value to `null` but you want to pass in an `undefined` to clear the filter.

Hope that helps you out on your quest!

Comment: How do you learn how to do stuff like that? @jh3y Do you read the whole documentation? Do you watch videos a lot? Any pointers for a noob?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that's the best approach to get it to reset like that but it does work. Tbh, I just looked at your plunker and figured a plain javascript tertiary statement was probably the best fit for your needs as you want to pass an undefined `id` when it has been set to `null`. In most cases playing with different approaches in the debugger, referring to the docs and surfing around here will find you an answer :D